# @client.event returning an output from an if condition that is false

Tags: python-3.x, events, conditional-statements, discord.py

What's The Problem?

In the following code

```
@client.event
    async def on_message(messag):
      if cur == ":gem:":  #checks if the currency (defined previously in the code) is gems
        
        if "gem" in messag.content.lower():
          await ctx.send("noticed bid of g.e.m.s.") #to prevent the bot from detecting its own message i used g.e.m.s for testing purposes
        elif "gems" in messag.content.lower():
          await ctx.send("noticed bid of g.e.m.s.")
        elif ":gem:" in messag.content.lower():
          await ctx.send("noticed bid of g.e.m.s.")
        else:
          pass

        if "gem" not in messag.content.lower():
          if "gems" not in messag.content.lower():
            await messag.author.send("This auction only accepts bids in :gem: gems. Please be more attentive before bidding")
        else:
          pass
```

when the string "gem" or "gems" is NOT in the message sent by a user, it sends a DM to them as intended, however the bot also sends the message "noticed bid of g.e.m.s." in the channel where the command was invoked (not in the DM to that person). This event code is after the bot sends an embed when a user runs the command. I have not included the embed's code for the sake of simplicity.

The solution I want

The bot only does the things under the if conditions that are True

Comment: What is `ctx`? Where have you defined it??

Comment: ctx is the command context . this event is under a command so theres nothing to worry about it @ŁukaszKwieciński

Comment: Are you defining the `on_message` event inside the command?

Comment: yes @ŁukaszKwieciński, i have done other types of events within commands multiple times before without any issue

Comment: That's not really a good idea, you're overwriting the other events. You should use [`wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) instead

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński however when i use wait _for, only one message is awaited from the user. i want infinite until the timeout occurs. If that is possible using wait _for i'd love to know how to do that. I was unable to find how to do that and i resorted to using an event instead

Comment: Use a loop, if you want one "shared" timeout you should use something like [`async_timeout`](https://github.com/aio-libs/async-timeout)